# INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED - Uppercase Package Name

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Unfortunately, I wrote an application through Android Studio with Kotlin a year ago, and my mistake was that I used capital letters for the package name (package: RubinoPro.ir). Meaning (I tested it and it is easy to install when all the letters are lowercase)

When there are capital letters, this error occurs at runtime

The application could not be installed: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED

Android Manifest codes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"


    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">





    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />


    <uses-permission


        android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"


        android:maxSdkVersion="32" />


    <uses-permission


        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"


        android:maxSdkVersion="32"


        tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO" />


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO" />


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />


    <uses-permission


        android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"


        tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />





    <queries>


        <package android:name="ir.resaneh1.iptv" />


        <package android:name="app.rbmain.a" />


        <package android:name="app.rubino.main" />


    </queries>





    <application


        android:name=".config.App"


        android:allowBackup="true"


        android:hardwareAccelerated="false"


        android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"


        android:label="@string/app_name"


        android:largeHeap="true"


        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"


        android:roundIcon="@drawable/app_icon"


        android:supportsRtl="false"


        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApplication">


        <meta-data


            android:name="firebase_messaging_auto_init_enabled"


            android:value="false" />


        <meta-data


            android:name="firebase_analytics_collection_enabled"


            android:value="false" />


        <meta-data


            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"


            android:value="RubinoProChannel" />


        <meta-data


            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"


            android:resource="@color/AppColorLight" />


        <meta-data


            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"


            android:resource="@drawable/app_icon" />





        <activity


            android:name=".LoginRubikaActivity"


            android:configChanges="orientation"


            android:exported="false"


            android:label="@string/title_activity_login_rubika"


            android:screenOrientation="portrait"


            android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApplication"


            tools:ignore="LockedOrientationActivity" />


        <activity


            android:name=".RubikaFileManagerActivity"


            android:configChanges="orientation"


            android:exported="false"


            android:label="@string/title_activity_rubika_file_manager"


            android:screenOrientation="portrait"


            android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApplication"


            tools:ignore="LockedOrientationActivity" />


        <activity


            android:name=".MainActivity"


            android:configChanges="orientation"


            android:exported="true"


            android:screenOrientation="portrait"


            android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApplication"


            tools:ignore="LockedOrientationActivity">


            <intent-filter android:label="روبینو پرو">


                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />


                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />





                <data android:mimeType="message/*" />


                <data android:mimeType="multipart/*" />


                <data android:mimeType="text/*" />


            </intent-filter>





            <intent-filter>


                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />





                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />


            </intent-filter>


            <intent-filter>


                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />





                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />


                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />





                <data android:scheme="http" />


                <data android:host="dl.rubinopro.ir" />


            </intent-filter>


            <intent-filter tools:targetApi="m">


                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />





                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />


                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />





                <data android:scheme="http" />


                <data android:host="rubinopro" />


            </intent-filter>


            <intent-filter>


                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />





                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />


                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />





                <data android:scheme="http" />


                <data android:host="www.dl.rubinopro.ir" />


            </intent-filter>


            <intent-filter tools:targetApi="m">


                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />





                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />


                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />





                <data android:scheme="https" />


                <data android:host="rubinopro" />


            </intent-filter>


            <intent-filter>


                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />





                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />


                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />





                <data android:scheme="https" />


                <data android:host="www.dl.rubinopro.ir" />


            </intent-filter>


            <intent-filter>


                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />





                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />


                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />





                <data android:scheme="lunch" />


                <data android:host="dl.rubinopro.ir" />


            </intent-filter>


            <intent-filter>


                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />





                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />


                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />





                <data android:scheme="lunch" />


                <data android:host="rubinopro" />


            </intent-filter>


            <intent-filter>


                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />





                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />


                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />





                <data android:scheme="lunch" />


                <data android:host="www.dl.rubinopro.ir" />


            </intent-filter>


            <intent-filter>


                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />





                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />


                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />





                <data android:scheme="https" />


                <data android:host="dl.rubinopro.ir" />


            </intent-filter>


            <intent-filter>


                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />





                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />


                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />





                <data android:scheme="https" />


                <data android:host="dl.rubinopro.ir" />


            </intent-filter>


        </activity>





        <provider


            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"


            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"


            android:exported="false"


            android:grantUriPermissions="true">


            <meta-data


                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"


                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />


        </provider>


        <service


            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService"


            android:exported="false">


            <intent-filter>


                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />


            </intent-filter>


        </service>


    </application>





</manifest>
```